# Macrotise proc format in SAS

Tags: sas, format, sas-macro

I've created a user defined format by using proc format statements.Would like to create a macro over it in a way that if the input data changes, the code should able to do change accordingly.

Here is the code:

```
  proc format ;
  value $a 1='1-sepstrata'
  0='0-Non-sepstrata'
  A='A-sepstrata';
  run;
```

In the dateset I've,a columns named stratum which has unique values such as 1,0,A.

Comment: I am not sure how macro would help. If you just want to attach your format to your variable use a FORMAT statement.  If you have both the code and the decode in a dataset then use that with the CNTLIN= option of PROC FORMAT to create your format definition from data.  Do you have a dataset with 1,0,A in one variable and corresponding text in another variable?

Comment: Hi Tom,thanks. I have 1,0,A in one column, corresponding texts I don't have. I need to define it based on a condition(which is if is it 0 then it should be "Non-sepstrata", otherwise anything else would have a "-sepstrata" attached to the value.

Comment: Could you also please help me know how to achieve this based on the CNTLIN= option.

Comment: Read the documentation at [Input Control Data Set](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p0owa4ftikc2ekn1q0rmpulg86cx.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p05g1cdvff8h8tn1frtzxrnkzezo)

Answer (score 3):

Select the distinct values of STRATA and use it to generate the format definition in a file. Then use PROC FORMAT to create the format.

```
proc sql;
  create table fmtdef as
    select '$A' as fmtname 
         , strata as start 
         , catx('-',strata
               ,case when (strata='0') then 'Non-sepstrata' else 'sepstrata' end
               ) as label
    from have
    group by strata
    order by fmtname,start 
  ;
quit;
proc format lib=work.formats cntlin=fmtdef; 
run;
```